# Pixel level landcover change analysis

Tags: raster, r, sf, land-cover, terra

I have two land cover maps in `Geotiff` format and need guidance on conducting a pixel-level change analysis.

```
library(raster)

set.seed(123)
raster1 <- raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100)
raster1[] <- sample(1:5, size = ncell(raster1), replace = TRUE)
extent(raster1) <- extent(0, 10, 0, 10)
projection(raster1) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84"

set.seed(456)
raster2 <- raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100)
raster2[] <- sample(1:5, size = ncell(raster2), replace = TRUE)
extent(raster2) <- extent(0, 10, 0, 10)
projection(raster2) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84"

# define the land cover classes
land_cover_classes <- 1:5

# data frame to store the change information
change_data <- data.frame(From_Class = integer(0), To_Class = integer(0), Area = numeric(0))

# Loop through each class
for (from_class in land_cover_classes) {
  for (to_class in land_cover_classes) {
    # Calculate the area of change from from_class to to_class
    change_cells <- sum((raster1[] == from_class) & (raster2[] == to_class))
    
    # Calculate the area in square meters
    area <- change_cells * res(raster1)[1] * res(raster1)[2]
    
    # Append the information to the data frame if there is a change
    if (area > 0) {
      change_data <- rbind(change_data, data.frame(From_Class = from_class, To_Class = to_class, Area = area))
    }
  }
}

change_data
```

In the above code I am using `raster` package which I think is being retired, I also think I might be following a longer route. Can someone recommend R resources or workflows for this purpose?

Comment: What do they look like? Are they the same resolution? How big? Same set of land cover classes? What have you tried? What sort of analysis? At the most basic level its just a table of old pixel values vs new pixel values. This is a very vague question...

Comment: @Spacedman I have now edited the question and provide more details and sample code.

Comment: We don't really do recommendations here. Ask a well-defined question, eg something like "How can I compute what percentage of each land use class has changed into each other class for all classes?" and you should get an answer with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, that double loop is quite unnecessary :) You can use the `terra::crosstab` function to evaluate class-level change. We will move this analysis to terra so that the depreciation of raster will not be an issue. First let's create some dummy data. We will smooth time 1 with two different window sizes to create some degree of associated pattern.

```
library(terra)
    
r1 <- rast(nrows=180, ncols=360, xmin=571823.6, xmax=616763.6, ymin=4423540, 
          ymax=4453690, resolution=200, crs = "EPSG:32612")
  r1[] <- sample(1:5, ncell(r1), replace=TRUE)        
r2 <- focal(r1, w=5, "median")
  names(r2) <- "LULC2020"
r1 <- focal(r1, w=3, "median")
  names(r1) <- "LULC1999"

plot(c(r1,r2))
```

[image: LULC]

Now we can calculate the cross-tabulation of the two LULC dates.

```
( chg <- crosstab(c(r1,r2)) )
chg * res(r1)[1]^2
```

There are also some additional ways to look at change via a moving window. The `spatialEco::raster.change` function provides the following statistical measures of change: "kappa", "t.test", "cor", "entropy", "cross-entropy", "divergence". The `spatialEco::raster.entropy` derives Entropy for a raster at a specified window size. For change detection you can calculate Entropy for the two timesteps and take the delta. Depending on the direction, it will represent gain or loss of classes within the window. The `spatialEco::raster.modified.ttest` provides an autocorrelation corrected version of the standard t.test.

```
library(spatialEco)

rttest <- raster.change(r1, r2, s=5, stat = "t.test")
rkappa <- raster.change(r1, r2, s=5, stat = "kappa")
  names(rkappa) <- "Kappa"

  diff <- r2 == r1
  names(diff) <- "difference"

plot(c(diff, rttest, rkappa))
```

[image: statistical diff]